# How do I render a CIImage into a 32-bits-per channel floating-point pixel buffer?

Tags: floating-point, core-image, ciimage, core-video, cvpixelbuffer

I want to render a CIImage into a pixel buffer of type kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat. But CIContext.render() fails saying "unsupported format". I tested on the iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 11.

Here's my code:

```
let context = CIContext()
var buffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
let buffer = CVPixelBufferCreate(nil,
                                 width,
                                 height,
                                 kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat,
                                 nil,
                                 &buffer)
assert(buffer != nil, "Couldn't create buffer")
context.render(ciImage, to: buffer)
```

The buffer is created successfully — the assertion doesn't fire. It's only the rendering in the last line that fails saying "unsupported format".

I also tried creating an [IOSurface-backed CVPixelBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1781/_index.html) by replacing the second nil with `[kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey: [:]] as CFDictionary`, but it didn't help.

How do I get this to work?

The format needs to be kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat, for reason that are too complex to get into here, the short version being that  the pixel values have a greater range than 0-255, including fractional values that cannot be rounded.

I tried some more things:

- [kCVPixelFormatType_64ARGB](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/kcvpixelformattype_64argb)
- The [software renderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/kcicontextusesoftwarerenderer)
- Creating the CIContext backed by an [EAGLContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1620419-init)
- Creating the CIContext backed by an [MTLDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437609-init)
- Calling CIContext.[createCGImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437978-createcgimage)()
- Rendering to a  MTLTexture‌‌ but I couldn't figure out how to create one.
- Rendering to an IOSurface
- Calling [clearCaches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437790-clearcaches)() on CIContext().
- Calling [reclaimResources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437967-reclaimresources)(), but that's not available on iOS.
- Checking that my input is < CIContext.[inputImageMaximumSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1620425-inputimagemaximumsize)() and [outputImageMaximumSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1620335-outputimagemaximumsize)()
- rendering to a [raw](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437897-render) byte array.

None of these worked. Is rendering to 32-bits per channel floats or 16 bits per channel ints not supported by Core Image?

Answer (score 0):

If 16 bits per channel is enough, you can render using [kCVPixelFormatType_64RGBAHalf](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/kcvpixelformattype_64rgbahalf).